# Show results of count condition in separate columns in Oracle SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, count, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table of which I am using GROUP BY to generate a count of a condition in a separate column based on whether or not the Call Letters are listed in the table with more than one propagation method.

```
 SELECT p.CallLetters, COUNT(p.PropMethod)
 FROM logpropmethod p
 GROUP BY p.CallLetters
 HAVING COUNT(p.PropMethod) > 1
```

This generates a result of:

```
 WIBC   3
 WQLZ   2
 WWVR   2
 CIBX   2
 WTTS   3
 WFBQ   2
 WCBH   2
 WKSV   2
```

What I want to be able to do is list the Propagation Methods in separate columns in the GROUPBY result.  There are only three different propagation methods, so I envision the results being listed in a PROPMETHOD1, PROPMETHOD2, PROPMETHOD3 column.  I can't quite figure out how to do this without resulting in a "not a GROUP BY expression" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CallLetters, COUNT(*) as total
    SUM(CASE WHEN PropMethod = 'PROPMETHOD1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PROPMETHOD1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PropMethod = 'PROPMETHOD2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PROPMETHOD2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PropMethod = 'PROPMETHOD3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PROPMETHOD3
FROM logpropmethod
GROUP BY CallLetters
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```